# Joint CDF and Integrals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the joint CDF $F(x,y)$ for the following function.
[image]

The following model answer was given.

[image]

My query is why we need to consider the first case $0<x<y$ when $f_{X,Y}$ is only defined above $0<y<x$? Furthermore I do not understand what the variables $u$ and $v$ refer to in the integration. Do they refer to some new axis $u,v$? Do small $x$ and small $y$ represent any $x, y$ value, or do they refer to a point on the line $Y=X$?

Answer (score 1):

When $0<x<y$, even though the pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$, the region that must be integrated over to get the cdf still contains a sub-region where the pdf is non-zero, so the integration must be performed. In addition, the region arising from the intersection of the cdf region ($0<u<x,0<v<y$) and the support of the pdf has different forms depending on whether $x<y$ or $y<x$, so we cannot combine the calculations of the two cases together.

$u,v$ are merely integration variables used to avoid conflicting with $x,y$, which are the upper bounds for the cdf region.

Comment: I cannot understand the part on sub-region of the CDF. Is there some software I can use to visualise this?

Comment: @NetUser5y62 The diagrams in your question can help visualise this. For example, the sub-region over which we integrate for the cdf at A is the trapezoidal, green region within the rectangle with opposite corners as the origin and A.

Comment: Actually could you please provide more details of the first line of your explanation? I interpret that over the domain 0<x<y, f_{X,Y} = 0 means that the surface has no z-value and thus has no volume, so the probability over that region is 0. Exactly which region is it that "must be integrated over to get the cdf"? I thought this would only be the green region, over which f_{X,Y} is a 3D surface and hence has volume and therefore non-zero probability?

Comment: @NetUser5y62 Yes, you integrate over the green region _that lies within the rectangle with opposite corners at the origin and A_.